# Insight into thermal energy

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

In thermal physics, we have heat flux $J$ given by $$J=-\kappa \nabla T.$$

Now assuming we have some closed object with closed surface $S$, the total heat flow out of $S$ is given by $$\int_S J\cdot dS.$$ This can be expressed as the rate of change of the total thermal energy inside the volume $V$ which is surrounded by the closed surface $S$.

In this case, why can we write the thermal energy as the volume integral $\int_V CT dV$, where $C$ here is the heat capacity per unit volume, i.e., dQ=dC/dT? I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain this intuitively with sound mathematical reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with an arbitrary vector field $\mathbf f$ there is the so-called divergence [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) according to which for an arbitrary closed volume $\mathcal V$ whose surface is $\partial \mathcal V$ we have:
$$\oint_{\partial \mathcal V} \mathbf f \cdot d\mathbf {\mathcal S} = \int_{\mathcal V} \text{div} \mathbf f dV$$
In your case $\mathbf f = \mathbf J = -\kappa \mathbf {grad} T$, therefore
$$-\oint_{\partial \mathcal V} \kappa \mathbf {grad} T \cdot d\mathbf {\mathcal S}= -\int_{\mathcal V} \text{div} (\kappa \mathbf {grad} T)dV$$
This integral is the total energy rate in the *volume* enclosed by the surface $\mathcal S$. Taken per unit volume it is an energy rate $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-\text{div} (\kappa \mathbf {grad} T)$ that is the rate of the internal energy $u=u(T)$ if thermal expansion of the volume element can be neglected, that is: $$c\frac{dT}{dt} = -\text{div} (\kappa \mathbf {grad} T)$$ where the heat capacity is defiend by $c=\frac{\partial u}{\partial T}.$